# How to clone previous repo version to local machine?

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-commit

I accidentally deleted all internal files from online GitHub repo - directory is now empty but still in existence - PLUS the repo has been removed from  local machine as well

Normally a GitHub clone would be used to get repo back on machine, git revert etc for online version, but this will not work for obvious reasons

How does one revert back to previous version of the project (one commit behind current) in this situation?

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DON'T PANIC!  There are [many ways to undo commits and pushes in Git](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things).

First, clone the repository.  It will download the full history of the project.

Then you can revert the commit using `git revert HEAD`.  This will add a new commit to undo the last one.  Then simply push that commit as normal.  This is the simplest thing to do, but it leaves a bad commit in the history.

Your other option is to undo the commit.  This can be done by moving the master branch back one commit.  Moving branches around arbitrarily is done with `git reset`.  `git reset --hard HEAD^`.  `HEAD^` is the commit before the current one.  `--hard` says to act like checkout and make your working directory match `HEAD^`.  I have `git reset --hard HEAD^` aliased to `undo`.  Then push the commit, but you will have to use `git push --force` because you are not adding on top of the existing commit.

This, btw, is why it is a bad habit to push after every commit.  It is much easier to undo changes which have not been pushed.

Comment: crisis averted.... thankyou for your very clear and well written reply, I have followed said instructions and am glad to say I still have a job as Junior Dev (barely)... Excellent 'supermaning', thanks Schwern

Comment: @Mervodactyl You're quite welcome! I'm glad it worked out. One of the great things about version control is it makes development very forgiving of dumb mistakes, especially if you release the idea that history is immutable.